# Count maximum occurences and find the corresponding value in excel

Tags: excel

I am struggling with a question in excel. Below is the sample data. I need to find the driver's name and his employee id who delivered maximum items. I am not sure how to use Index Match / Count / MAX in this case:

```
Emp ID    Driver Name   Item
1            Peter      TV
2            John       Microwave
3            Carl       Washing Machine
1            Peter      TV
1            Peter      Microwave
```

By looking at the sample, I know the answer is Peter, but how to find this value using formula.

I also need to find how many Drivers delivered most items. In this scenario, the answer is 1 (Peter) Trying to use countif here, didn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@BigBen's solution didn't work for me because MODE.SNGL seems to be a child of Excel 365 which I don't have. If you are in the same situation, the following will work on earlier versions of Excel.

Extract the name with
[G2] `=INDEX(Names,MODE(MATCH(Names,Names,0)))`
and the Employee ID with

```
=INDEX(EmpID,MATCH(G2,Names,0))
```

Replace "G2" in this formula with the first formula if you don't want to refer to the name extracted by it.

Both formulas are written using named ranges for the columns of Employee IDs and Drive Names. This is to make them easier to read and edit. It also makes them easier to manage because you can define the named range dynamically.

Comment: Thank You @Variatus. But don't I need to refer Column C at all in this case?

Additionally, I have another question. How can I calculate which Driver delivered more than 1 item from the given data? Again in this scenario, we can see that Peter delivered 2 item. How to find the name Peter in this case?

Comment: No, column C is irrelevant. The two named ranges can be in any columns, however, and they need not be adjacent. Your additional question I can't answer off the cuff. I'll come back here if I can think of something. Better ask a new question to get more attention.

Comment: For your additional requirement I suggest a helper column with a COUNTIF() function in it.

Answer (score 0):

To get the Employee ID:

```
=MODE.SNGL(A2:A6)
```

To get the name:

```
=INDEX(B2:B6,MATCH(MODE.SNGL(A2:A6),A2:A6,0))
```

[image]

In case there is a "tie", use `MODE.MULT` instead of `MODE.SNGL`. Depending on your version of Excel, you may have to enter the formula with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd>.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the response BigBen. Can you please let me know how the same formula will work considering the columns B and C only. Assuming Column A doesn't exist. For example, since Peter delivered 2 TVs and a Microwave, how can I find Peter's name using the same formula?

Comment: @AdvaitKulkarni `=INDEX(B2:B6,MODE(MATCH(B2:B6,B2:B6,0)))` Depending on your version you may need use Ctrl-Shift-Enter instead of Enter when exiting edit mode.

Comment: Thanks @ScottCraner for your reply. Can you please also let me know how to find the number of drivers who delivered more than 1 product. In this case the answer should be 1 (Peter) since he delivered 2 items. But, how to find it?

Comment: @AdvaitKulkarni - as a note, it would help to keep your question to one issue only. If you keep changing the requirements, it's harder to help.

Comment: Hi @BigBen I am working on an assignment where I have been asked a series of questions. I can't show the data right away, which is why I am trying to ask different questions through the example above. Therefore, based on above example, I am also trying to find ''How many drivers delivered more than 1 item."